# Can gravitational waves be refracted or reflected?

Tags: gravitational-waves

Graviatational waves are influenced by gravitational lensing. But are there other ways to influence gravitational waves?
Could we build reflectors or refracting systems to concentrate gravitational waves to like in telescopes for electromagnetic waves?

Comment: We already have seen them refracted by stars or black holes, I believe.   I'm hard-pressed to imagine a "normal matter"  or EM field which could reflect the waves.